# How to check FileUploader have file in MVC4 asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an application in mvc4. In edit mode i want user to edit his/her details,
user have option to change his profile image by selecting from fileuploader. But if user do not select file in uploader the previous file location will be sent.
I am storing image path in table same as other details.
So, only one Stored procedure is created.
I am only 1 day old in mvc.Started working on mvc directly, without studying by seniors order.
So pls help

Answer (score 0):

The following code is on the assumption that you save the file's name in the db table and save the file on the app server.

The code will be as follows:

Model:

```
public string Photo {get;set;}
```

View :

```
<input type='file' id='file'/> 
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Photo)
```

JS :

```
// if there is a photo update by user, change the Photo hidden element value
//get the final name of the photo saved in server    
$("#Photo").val(newname);
```

Then simply post your form.

In case, the user doesn't change its photo, then the previous value will remain in the hidden element and updated to the db. Hence, nothing will actually change in the photo column.

I strongly recommend [this tutorial for MVC beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/486161/Creating-a-simple-application-using-MVC).

Comment: comment here if you dont understand

Comment: I will try it immidiately.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to use strongly typed models. You should create a separater ViewModel for your User:

Models/UserEditViewModel

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
// Other properties

public HttpPostedFileBase Photo { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    // Get user from database
    var user = db.Users.Find(id);

    // Map user to UserEditViewModel
    var userVM = new UserEditViewModel
        {
            Id = user.Id;
            Name = user.Name;
            // Other mappings
        }
    return View(userVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit(UserEditViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var existingUser = db.Users.Find(model.Id);

        if (model.Photo != null && model.Photo.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // Update database and copy image to server
        }

    }
}
```

View:

```
@model YourProject.Models.UserEditViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    // Form stuff
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Photo) // Creates <input type="file" name="Photo" />

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```